# Any firefox plugin that can cache entire page and load it when accessed using url

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am looking for a firefox plugin that can store entire page in cache and load it when ever that address is typed, and only load content from server if we press reload cache or similar functionality.

My usecase is, I use documentation of Laravel, Bootstrap, Jquery etc on regularly based but each time I am accessing it from the internet, these pages do not have any changes for many days. I dont want to store the webpage as file and access it, I would love to do it in comfort of your web browser than opening files.

Answer (score 0):

I think firefox already does this. Load a page in a tab, then go to top left firefox menu > developer > work offline.

Reload that page in tab its from cache.

If you ever go work offline it loads from cache.